# Using AWS Cognito User Pools, Federated Identity Provider, and AWS Amplify

Tags: reactjs, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

Is there a way to allow a user to sign in through a Federated Identity Provider ( I'm currently trying Amazon itself ) via the AWS Amplify SDK when you configure the Cognito User Pool to allow it?  I tried creating a new react app according to the instructions on the AWS Amplify site, then tried to use the withAuthenticator HOC?  All I get is

Token is not from a supported provider of this identity pool